# vertical infinity carousel in jquery from scratch

Tags: jquery

I'm tring to create a vertical infinity carousel in Jquery for the purpose of learning , the carousel works just fine for the first cicle but after that it stops and start duplicating elements... anyone knows what i did wrong ?

```
 Thank you.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/boumaig/685TP/2/

```
        $(function($){
            $next = $('.next');
            $list = $('li');
            $q    = 0;

            var aux = {
                 clone_ithem : function(list){
                    this.list = list;
                    list.eq($q).clone(true).appendTo('ul')
                 },
                 remove_ithem : function(list){
                    this.list = list;
                    list.eq($q).remove();
                    if($q <= $list.length - 2){
                        $q++;
                    }else{
                        $q = 0;
                    }    
                }
            }

            $next.click(function(event){

                aux.clone_ithem($list);
                aux.remove_ithem($list);
                event.preventDefault();
            });
            //Jquery END Line
        });
```

Html Code :

```
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="nav">
        <a href="#" class="next">next</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: sorry i thought using jsfiddle would be enought to show my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of cloning and removing the element you can consider to switch the position by appending the first element at the end of the ul.

Code:

```
 $(function ($) {
     $next = $('.next');
     $list = $('ul');

     var aux = {
         clone_item: function (list) {
             this.list = list
             $(list).find('li:first').appendTo(list);
         }
     }

     $next.click(function (event) {
         aux.clone_item($list);
         event.preventDefault();
     });
 });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Tj4c2/